# Definition of Macdonald polynomial $P_\lambda^{\mathfrak{g}}$ associated to a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ (unlike $P_\lambda$)

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

I want to find the definition for the Macdonald polynomial associated to a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{c}_n$, i.e. $P_\lambda^{\mathfrak{c}_n}(x,t,q)$. This appears in the physics paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.12282.pdf, equation 2.9 and the explanation in the paragraphs below, citing Macdonald's book $\textit{Symmetric functions and orthogonal polynomials}$. My understanding is that for each partition $\lambda$ (i.e. Young diagram), there is a corresponding Macdonald polynomials $P_\lambda (x,q,t)$. The literature seems to indicate that this is implicitly the Macdonald polynomials of type $A_n$, i.e. $P_\lambda^{\mathfrak{a}_n}(x,q,t)$.

Ultimately, I want to know how to compute these $P_\lambda^{\mathfrak{c}_n}$, where I know how to compute $P_\lambda$ (or $P_\lambda^{\mathfrak{a}_n}$ if I am not wrong). In short, what is $P_\lambda^{\mathfrak{c}_n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Macdonald's book, as you indicated, he is implicitly working with type $A_{n}$ throughout. The key for Macdonald polynomials of type $C_{n}$ as opposed to $A_{n}$ lies in understanding Equation (9.10) on p.372, which is written specifically for type $A_{n}$. More generally

\begin{equation}
\langle f,g \rangle_{q,t}^{W} = \frac{1}{|W|}\int_{T}f(x)\overline{g(x)}\Delta(q,t) dz.
\end{equation}

Here the density function also needs to change from the standard Macdonald density to the generalized Macdonald density. You will find this as Equation (3.3) in Macdonald's paper *Orthogonal polynomials associated with root systems* (2000). So, the more general Macdonald polynomials $P_{\lambda}^{W}(x;q,t)$ correspond to a modified version of Theorem (4.7) on p. 322 of Macdonald's book. They are the unique family of $W$-symmetric functions such that

\begin{equation}
P_{\lambda}^{W}(q,t) = m_{\lambda}^{W} + \sum_{\mu < \lambda}u_{\lambda\mu}(q,t)m_{\mu}^{W},
\end{equation}

such that

\begin{equation}
\langle P_{\lambda}(q,t), P_{\mu}(q,t) \rangle_{q,t}^{W} = 0, \text{ whenever } \lambda \neq \mu.
\end{equation}

Here the $m^{W}$ are generalizations of the monomial symmetric functions you are familiar with from $A_{n}$. They can be defined by

\begin{equation}
m_{\lambda}^{W} = \sum_{\alpha \in \mathop{Orb}(\lambda,W)} x^{\alpha}.
\end{equation}

For $A_{n}$ these are simply permutations of monomials. For $C_{n}$ these are instead signed permutations as $W$ is instead the hyperoctahedral group. For example

\begin{equation}
m_{(1)}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) = x_{1} + x_{1}^{-1} + x_{2} + x_{2}^{-1} + x_{3} + x_{3}^{-1}.
\end{equation}